# Set conditional parameter to not output "dateUpdated" field, when entry is first time created

Tags: datetime

I was going through my code for testing purposes and found out, that When entry's first time created, it also outputs data from the field "dateUpdated". 
I'm assuming, when an entry is first time created it is also first time updated.

So I'm trying to write a conditional statement to not output "dateUpdated" for entries, that were first time created.

So far I didn't come up with anything, because I'm not sure If what I'm assuming is true.

For the start.

```
{# Date #}
<span>
     {{ "published"|t|ucwords }}: {{ entry.dateCreated is empty ? "" : entry.dateCreated|date("d.m.Y") }},
</span>
{% if entry.dateUpdated %}
      <span class="uk-text-success-alert">
            {{ "updated"|t|ucwords }}: {{ entry.dateUpdated is empty ? "" : entry.dateUpdated|date("d.m.Y") }},
      </span>
{% endif %}
{% if entry.expiryDate %}
      <span class="uk-text-danger">
            {{ "expire"|t|ucwords }}: {{ entry.expiryDate is empty ? "" : entry.expiryDate|date("d.m.Y") }},
      </span>  
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to the Craft scene, so forgive my naivety. However, just poking around the DB after an install and after creating entries etc I noticed that `dateCreated` and `dateUpdated` are entered at the same time. So, instead of checking for a value, could you check if `dateUpdated` is after `dateCreated`?

Comment: The values must to be the same as they are populated at the same time.

Comment: Or you mean, the position in the row of the entry field? If so, Yes it is.

Comment: It's entirely possible I'm reading your question wrong, but if you only want to show the updated if in fact the record was updated and not initially created, then you would just check the two dates - and if the `datedUpdated` date is after the `dateCreated` then that should work I think...

Comment: Well, I only need to output the `dateCreated` and in condition `dateUpdated` and `expiryDate` for entry. So I have to write some conditional statement, where I compare times. It must to be easy, just hard to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's where I'm going to be more help in theory, rather than code. But maybe something like this? I'm happy to revise if someone sees a typo.

```
{# Date #}
<span>
     {{ "published"|t|ucwords }}: {{ entry.dateCreated is empty ? "" : entry.dateCreated|date("d.m.Y") }},
</span>
{% if entry.dateCreated != entry.dateUpdated %}
      <span class="uk-text-success-alert">
            {{ "updated"|t|ucwords }}: {{ entry.dateUpdated is empty ? "" : entry.dateUpdated|date("d.m.Y") }},
      </span>
{% endif %}
{% if entry.expiryDate|length %}
      <span class="uk-text-danger">
            {{ "expire"|t|ucwords }}: {{ entry.expiryDate is empty ? "" : entry.expiryDate|date("d.m.Y") }},
      </span>  
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Haven't encountered on any problem yet.  If I don't, I tick this answer for the correct one. Nice one. Thanks @dragonslovetacos

Comment: Awesome! Let me know if you do - my twig/craft skills are still at level "rookie" :)

Comment: I'm somewhere at "half-rookie" level :) A long way ahead! Anyway, comparison understood, it gives the logic and most important IT WORKS, because human mind has built it :) Thank you again @dragonslovetacos